# Will local version labels be shown in the __version__ attribute?

Tags: python-3.x

If I install a package from source, and inside of its `setup.cfg`, it has the following:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build = +source
```

when I do `import foobar_package; print(foobar_package.__version__)`, will the `+source` show up in the output?

Answer (score 0):

They are not shown. I tried printing `__version__`, and the `+source` was not present.